# I get duplicated registry

Tags: php, mysql, database

i need to help with MySQL Query.

i'm doing a permission CRUD on PHP and i can't get the correct query to get all permissions that doesn't have certain role like "admin" doesn't have "clientpanel" permission, the problem is that if "client" and "admin" role has the same permission(access) like "products", the query shows me the "product permission id" from "client"
Here is the Query:

```
SELECT permission.perm_desc 
    FROM role_perm 
INNER JOIN roles 
    ON role_perm.role_id =roles.role_id 
INNER JOIN permission 
    ON role_perm.perm_id = permission.perm_id 
WHERE role_perm.role_id != 1
```

i'm getting results permission from other Roles, i want to filter to show the ones who doesn't have. this is freaking me out.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM role_perm 
LEFT JOIN roles 
    ON role_perm.role_id =roles.role_id 
LEFT JOIN permission 
    ON role_perm.perm_id = permission.perm_id 
WHERE role_perm.role_id = 1
```

I've deliberately left the final parts of the problem as an exercise for the reader